# C++ CreateFile gives Access is Denied error with full file path

Tags: c++, file, io

I have a program that takes in two file names as arguments and reads them. Since the files were also in the same folder, I never had any issues. But recently, I tried passing in the absolute path for files located in another folder, and I got an invalid handle with the **error code Access is Denied** (this was from calling `getLastError()`).

So I tested by giving the absolute path to couple of files in the same folder (the ones that work when I just pass in the file name). To my surprise, it returned an invalid handle and gave the same error code. My code is below:-

```
std::wstring stemp = s2ws(argv[1]);
LPCWSTR test = stemp.c_str();

testfile  = CreateFile(test, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
```

I am not sure what is wrong so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You need to call GetLastError() to find out what the error code is (this is pretty clearly stated in the docs.)

Comment: Yes, I did call it, and the error is code #5, access is denied! I didn't include the code above of me calling it, but I did mention the error code I received.

Comment: Your code sample is not complete. You have to post the contents of `test` string if you want someone to help you. Maybe simply the path is not correct or the file you want to open does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean it does not exist? I just told you it exists because I can read it if I don't give a full path when its in the same folder??
Also, if the file does not exist, then the error code is different.

Comment: If one of the parent directories and/or the file are created with administrative account and you're running your program as limited user that could also be the cause. There's just not enough information in your post to analyze it more. I, and other, can just guess one thing after another until we accidentally come to a solution.

Comment: Well, suppose its an administrative issue, then does it make sense that I see a difference in behavior when specifying full path vs. file name when the files are in the current folder?

Comment: @TonyJ: it can, if the process's current working directory is different than what you are expecting, and so opening the files using relative paths is opening them from somewhere completely unexpected that you *happen* to have access to, but you don't have access to the files you are opening with absolute paths in a different folder. I suggest you use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see exactly what files you are actually opening when using relative paths, and compare that to your absolute paths. Or use `GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Which Kind of operationg System are you using? And what is the absolute path you give? If there are backslashes `\\` in the path, did you escape them `\\\` ?

Comment: @milbrandt: `CreateFile()` and `GetLastError()` are Microsoft Win32 functions, so the OS is clearly Windows. And escaping backslashes only applies when using string literals in code at compile-time, not when obtaining data at run-time (in this case, from a command line parameter)

Comment: Hello, thank you Remy and BJovke! I tried what you said and it seems to be a problem with converting from string to wstring. Initially I just looked at the strings and thought everything was ok. If I try to print out variable test by converting it back to string, it is correct when I just pass in the file name. But it is just couple of garbage characters when I try the full path name. I am thinking that it might be due to the extra characters present in the path like ":" and "\" are not being converted properly. I will try replacing my s2ws and see if it helps.